# I keep getting NPM err code 128 trying to install npm install AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the book example I'm trying to run but they have an deprecated Async storage so I'm using react-native-async-storage/async storage

https://github.com/warlyware/react-native-cookbook/blob/master/chapter-8/local-data-storage/App.js

I imported it as

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Get this error code
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage'.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

or i get
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: project4@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8" from @react-native-community/async-storage@1.12.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage
npm ERR!   @react-native-community/async-storage@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!

Already have done:

> npm install npm@latest -g

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the second error message. `npm i @react-native-community/async-storage --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: This helped and I also had to remove the async-store dependencies from my package.json and run npx install async-storage and npx expo-codemod sdk41-async-storage './**/*' in my files folder